# What could be the solutions forthe 'Appium SDK location error' encountered during Android app automation?

Tags: automation, appium

Encountered internal error running command: Error: The Android SDK root folder 'C:\Users\Win11 Pro\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist on the local file system. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details

How can i fixed this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjKM4.png)

App automation testing